# Translating a sentence with the て form

Tags: grammar, translation, て-form

［彼は］銀行に入って２年目にアメリカの大学に留学しました。

I'm not sure how I should translate this sentence. The text where I found it describes the life of a japanese guy who graduated from a japanese university and then was hired by a japanese firm.

Comment: Is 銀行 just a bank? What comes before this sentence? Which part you don't understand?

Comment: Yeah, it's the bank he works for. I don't understand the time relation between 銀行に入って and 留学しました.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is  2年目 に  "in the second year". The sentence means "In the second year after entering the bank, [he] studied at an American university". I'd go for something like "In his second year with the bank he went [presumably was sent] to study at an American university". Possibly even "He spent his second year with the bank studying at a university in America".

Comment: I think your translation reads like 2年目*は*アメリカに*ずっと*留学していました。 2年目に 留学しました implies only a specific point in  time in the year.

Comment: @someone - you're right. I was applying the principles of pragmatics: I know from my real-world (as opposed to linguistic) knowledge that a Japanese bank is likely to send an employee overseas for education or training and that such education is likely to last months or years. Hence my second suggested version. But it isn't supported by the text alone. I stand corrected,. Regards.